# Where does this code leak?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

Instruments is telling me that this code leaks.  Where?  Do I have to release conn?

```
- (void)loadFeatureXML:(id<BPLFeatureLoaderDelegate>)delegate {

    _delegate = delegate;

    NSURLConnection *conn;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myxmlfeed"]];
    if ([NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request]) {   
        conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (conn) {
        self.featureXMLData = [NSMutableData data];
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Instruments should also show you which object's are leaked and where they originate from.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you're leaking the delegate; why not:

```
self._delegate = delegate;
```

Like you have below for `self.featureXMLData`?

Comment: But if you overwrite that pointer without sending it a `release` or `autorelease` message, how does the system know to deallocate the old one?  I guess without seeing other code that sets `_delegate` it's hard to tell - I don't see any other problems leaping out.

Comment: Further, if you *do* have an explicit (ie non-synthesized) setter for featureXMLData it should be checked to make sure it's doing the right retain/release thing.